# "500?" from FTP in java console

Tags: java, sockets, networking, ftp, network-programming

I'm trying this Java code from Oracle docs for reading and writing to sockets (connection to ftp server), and I sucessfully got response from ftp server but I don't understand last line. It should be asking for username but I'm getting "500?"?

This is link with source code (just change server and port):
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html

This is c/p from Console:

```
echo: 220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------

echo: 220-You are user number 4 of 100 allowed.

echo: 220-Local time is now 00:07. Server port: 21.

echo: 220-This is a private system - No anonymous login

echo: 220-IPv6 connections are also welcome on this server.

echo: 220 You will be disconnected after 30 minutes of inactivity.

echo: 500 ?
```

So why I'm getting **500 ?** and why can't I login with my username and password?

Answer (score 0):

The code you linked to is for an echo client. It is sending the welcome message from the FTP server back to it. This is pretty obviously not a valid command in FTP. The server then sends 500 because that is the status code for an error. From wikipedia

> Syntax error, command unrecognized and the requested action did not
>   take place. This may include errors such as command line too long.

Comment: @CroatiaBoy I don't think you understand what I just said.